# collection error in grid

Tags: magento

My module breaks if I remove this var_dump line. why is like that. Is there anything wrong with my joins

```
    protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $collection = mage::getModel('faq/faq')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('s'=>'gagan_faq_creation'),
            'main_table.faq_id = s.faq_id');
    var_dump($collection->getData());

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I get this error

```
QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'faq_id' in order clause is ambiguous
#0 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
```

Comment: Try looking at the generated select from the query: echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); and running it against the database.  It's often a lot more obvious what the problem is when you're looking at raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting `faq_id` from both table (`main_table` & `gagan_faq_creation`) that,s why it's giving MySQL error, So need to add alliance  for gagan_faq_creation.faq_id.

Comment: Man that's weird but you were right, I dont' know whats making the collection confused. Would you be able to elaborate this for better understanding. I changed the Column name in gagan_faq_creation from faq_id to f_id and it works. Thank you, saved my lot of time.